# Switching monitors as in Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, unity, multiple-monitors

One thing I loved in Windows 7 was the ease of switching between single monitors/extending/mirroring them using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. This shortcut produced the following:

[image]

Is there something similar in Ubuntu? The only way I found is to either

1. use `Displays` settings, which is bothersomly slow
2. use <kbd>Fn</kbd> shortcut, which is not optimal, because you don't know, which mode you'll be turned to

Comment: There is not simple way to do that like in Win7 with a simple keyboard shortcut. You have to lauch the display setup tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I switched to XFCE, I am very happy with the XFCE's display swicher. It's as easy as hitting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and selecting the output via arrows and hitting <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>. Once you remember the shortcuts, it's lightning fast.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why is `Displays` slow? Because it is too many clicks away, or because changing what is needed (necessarily using mouse) is clumsy? If the former, you can either use the launcher with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, `displays` (or `disp` should be enough), <kbd>Enter</kbd>; and if that is not enough, use `ccsm` command bindings to invoke `gnome-control-center display` with one keystroke.

If the latter, I believe there still may be a remedy: if you are using say two or three typical monitor setups, you may use the command bindings as above for mapping appropriate `xrandr` invocations, e.g. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for the first setup, etc. You still will not see what configuration you are going to end up with, but you will know which one you are setting.

Comment: `Displays` is slow because of having to reach for mouse. Will investigate on `xrandr` more.